KTOR - Derialize POST request body with nested object
I have an object
@Serializable
data class Manufacturer(
    val uuid: String? = null,
    val name: String,
    val cars: List<CarModel> = emptyList()
)

That is used to convert a request body into an internal object. CarModel is defined as follows:
@Serializable
data class CarModel(val uuid: String? = null, val carType: String, val name: String)

Now I can define a request body
{
    "name": "Test Name",
}

And the request is successful, however when I add a list representing car models, the request fails with the error: Failed to convert request body to class
Here's an example request body
{
    "name": "Manufacturer 1",
    "cars": [
        {
            "car_type": "Sedan",
            "name": "Car 1",
        },
        {
            "car_type": "Sedan",
            "name": "Car 2",
        },
    ]
}

It seems like ktor is having trouble deserializing nested objects, which is why when I provide a list of cars, it fails, but I can't figure out how to work around this, when the CarModel itself is serializable, so in theory, should be implicitly supported? I can successfully send list of strings, I just am unable to handle custom objects.
EDIT: Added Stack Trace
2024-12-03 09:40:24.588 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [manufacturer]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /ws, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /ws
  /json, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /json
  /manufacturers, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /manufacturers
  /manufacturer, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /manufacturer
    /manufacturer/(method:POST), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /manufacturer/(method:POST)
  /tag, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /tag
Matched routes:
  "" -> "manufacturer" -> "(method:POST)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /manufacturer/(method:POST)
2024-12-03 09:40:24.650 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE i.k.server.engine.DefaultTransform - No Default Transformations found for class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel and expected type TypeInfo(type=class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer, reifiedType=class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer, kotlinType=com.carapp.models.Manufacturer) for call /manufacturer
2024-12-03 09:40:24.689 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages - Call /manufacturer failed with cause io.ktor.server.plugins.BadRequestException: Failed to convert request body to class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer
2024-12-03 09:40:24.714 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages - Executing (io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationCall, kotlin.Throwable) -> kotlin.Unit for exception io.ktor.server.plugins.BadRequestException: Failed to convert request body to class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer for call /manufacturer
2024-12-03 09:40:24.715 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping because body is already converted.



Can you please share the complete stack trace of the exception?

@AlekseiTirman Added

There should be a stack trace with the cause for BadRequestException. Can you wrap the call.receive() call in try/catch to get the entire stack trace?

It's just the Failed to convert request body to class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer exception mentioned in the post. The only other potentially relevant line I'm seeing is: No Default Transformations found for class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel and expected type TypeInfo(type=class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer, reifiedType=class com.carapp.models.Manufacturer, kotlinType=com.carapp.models.Manufacturer) for call /manufacturer?

@AlekseiTirman I wanted to follow up and see if you had any ideas on why this may be faillng?

As it turns out, the key I was using in the JSON when making the request to representCar.carType was incorrect - I was sending along car_type when I should have been sending carType as the JSON key, so the correct JSON body is actually:
{
    "name": "Manufacturer 1",
    "cars": [
        {
            "carType": "Sedan",
            "name": "Car 1",
        },
        {
            "carType": "Sedan",
            "name": "Car 2",
        },
    ]
}

